# Copy schema from one container to another

Tags: ios, cloudkit

In CloudKit Dashboard, I created Record Types in wrong container (another app).  Is there a way to copy or export/import schema to another container (another app)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no simple migration possible.

You could add 2 containers to your app and open them both. Then read 1 record from the first container (which at least have all the fields) and then write that record to the 2nd container. If you do that for all recordTypes, then at least you would have your recordType definitions in the 2nd database. All options like meta data indexes have to be set in the dashboard.

In my CloudKit convenience library [EVCloudKitDao](https://github.com/evermeer/EVCloudKitDao) I sort of have a solution for this. I have a method that just creates all the recordTypes of the objects that I use. It can be called like this:

```
EVCloudKitDao.publicDB.createRecordTypes([Message(), Asset(), News()])
```

Comment: Surprisingly, this is something big A does not see the need for it!